# UIDatePicker is not working with MonoTouch. Gives error "Unknown char: ."

Tags: char, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I have been trying to use the UIDatePicker, both trying to make my own projects and also trying to use tutorials from Wrox.

The problem is as soon as i have a UIDatePicker in my project, the xib file generates the error "Unknown char: .". It doesn't matter which SDK version or minimum OS version I choose in the solutions build options. And i don't have to create any outlets or write any code, so I have ruled out crappy code. ;) As soon as I use the datepicker in my xib file, I can't compile it anymore.

I installed Apple SDK, Mono, MonoTouch and MonoDevelop just a couple of days ago, so the software should be all the latest. Also: I get this error on two different Macs.

Is this a bug or a user error? :O

Comment: having the same problem with NSTableView when using MonoMac.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post a bug report to bugzilla.novell.com with the attached sample.